# How do I save data (text to .txt file, or image file to a directory on my hard drive) automatically with Flash As3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, save

I have a drawing app, which lets you save your drawing, but when you hit save it prompts the system dialogue box that asks where you want to save it. What I need is to save automatically to a specific location in a directory on my computer. Any ideas how to do this with Flash & As3? Do I really need to use php or xml to do this (I have been checking for possible solutions)?
Any help would be appreciated, I am really quite novice at programming and as3.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible unless you're using AIR. For obvious security reason, the Flash plug-in simply will not silently write to a file. Saving must be triggered by user action.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in pure as3.0, you can't save a file directly without a dialogue-box.

but, if you use a Air follow it

more information, see a Air documentation: [FileStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html), [File](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/com/adobe/livecycle/content/File.html)

```
var fileStream : FileStream = new FileStream();
var file : File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('your_file_name.jpg');
fs.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeBytes(your_byte_array);
fs.close();
```

Comment: Why don't you just give us example code for saving **with** dialog box? That's what **I** am looking for right now -.-